# 'give a facial expression' or 'have a facial expression'?

Tags: expressions

In this sentence:

> He gave a cynical expression on his face.

I'm confused if 'give' is the appropriate word in this case. Is it?

Comment: _Have_, not _give_. _Give_ requires an indirect object.

Comment: @Lawler, can 'make' or 'pull' be used in the sentence?

Comment: @arpon: He gave me a cynical look.  He made a cynical expression.  He *had* a cynical expression *on his face*.

Comment: @Lawler, what will be the appropiate preposition if I use an indirect object in this sentence? Is that correct to say, 'He gave a cynical expression at me.' ?

Comment: A facial expression is something your face *has* or *shows*. It is a property of your face. It is not something that you *give* to someone else.

Comment: No, you can give a look, because it's directional; but you can't give an expression. _Make an expression_ can be volitional, in which case it means to exaggerate some expression, the same as _pull a face_ (the metaphor is "pull a mask over one's face"). If the "face" is sufficiently stylized and directed, you can "pull a face" at someone, like _make_. But you can't pull an expression, either.

Comment: @JohnLawler: No. *Give* does **not** require an indirect object. *He gave a chuckle. She gave a speech. The lion gave a roar. They gave a round of applause.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you cannot give something "on your face" (to anyone). It is a logical issue. If something is on your face, it cannot be given. The most you can do is to give something from on your face, or perhaps make a face to someone. As *TRomano* said:

> He gave me a cynical look. ["look" can refer to a particular way of looking at a person.]
>
> He had a cynical look on his face. ["look" can also refer to an expression on the face.]
>
> He made a cynical expression. [Like "looks", "expressions" can be made.]
>
> He had a cynical expression on his face. ["had" refers to the point in time that it is on his face.]